# react-i18next use withTranslation got type and ref error, I don't how to fix

Tags: react-native, i18next, react-i18next

after use withTranslation, react-native ts got errors, ref error and type error, I don't know how to fix

[image]

[image]

```
    "i18next": "^23.5.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^13.2.2",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most easiest way to solve this error would be to follow your IDE's hint and make use of `typeof`

```
datePicker: React.RefObject<typeof DatePicker> = React.createRef<typeof DatePicker>()
```

What you are trying to do is following

```
const MyObject = {
 name: "Joe Doe",
 age: "99"
}

//Wrong
React.RefObject<MyObject> = React.createRef<MyObject>()

//Correct
React.RefObject<typeof MyObject> = React.createRef<typeof MyObject>()
```

Comment: yes, I did tried, but also have the second error from the page, property 'ref' does not exit, thanks for the answer, I will post a new answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

#### find a way to solve the two errors while use ts and ref and class component with react-i18next withTranslation

```js
datePickerRef: React.RefObject<DatePickerRef> = React.createRef<DatePickerRef>();
```

```js
//region withTranslation with ts and ref
//https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/fdab4e8953b2cdaf29d21d716d33ebfd0eca99f2/src/withTranslation.js#L5
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77677338/react-i18next-use-withtranslation-got-type-and-ref-error-i-dont-how-to-fix
//https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/1122#issuecomment-1859634674
export interface DatePickerRef extends DatePicker {}
export default withTranslation(undefined, { withRef: true })(DatePicker) as React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
  Omit<DatePickerProps, keyof WithTranslation> & RefAttributes<DatePickerRef>
>;
//endregion
```